# How to make an Android update for your own device?

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat, builds

I have [this devices](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Amoi-N828-Smartphone.93161.0.html) which the android version is 4.2. After read some articles about Kitkat, I'm really excited and want to try to experience it on my phone. However, it seems the manufacturer won't update it to Kitkat in the future. So I think I'll do it my own. I understand and accept the risks.

So, what should I do now? I read some articles about this but can't make a check list of things to do. Will it be [a build from the scratch](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-building-android-from-source) or I can re-use the old kernel? How can I extract the old driver?

If someone can provide me a guide or a check list, it will help me so much! Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: @bmdixon: Thank for the link, I'm interested in the unoffical part, but I like to know how to make the updates myself, not wait for developers...

Comment: You're probably best looking at [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/30530) question then. Personally i'd say that XDA is probably best but there are plenty of others sites mentioned in that question that would help.

Comment: Thank @bmdixon. If I found something interesting I would post it here. Hope you guys do it too!